# php artisan creates controller with "use App\Http\Controllers\Controller" but it is never used

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-artisan

When I create a controller in Laravel with the php artisan command

```
php artisan make:controller TestController
```

it create a controller which includes

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller
```

PhpStorm hints: *Alias "App\Http\Controllers\Controller" is never used.*

This seems to be correct because the part

```
class TestController extends Controller
```

works fine without it. So can I remove the "use App\Http\Controllers\Controller" or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can safely remove that `use` statement.  Inside of any given namespace you can safely reference any other class that is also inside of that namespace *without* having to provide a fully qualified name to it.  Since both `TestController` and `Controller` are in the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace, then you should have no issue if you wish to remove that line.

If you move `TestController` or `Controller` to a different namespace, then you will need to import the `Controller` class inside of your `TestController`.